# Is there an javafx api to customize title bar?

Tags: java, windows, javafx, titlebar

I'm working on project to manage users PC, but I need to customize the application title bar, like adding search bar or account info in it like ms teams

If someone knows an API that can do it for me, please help.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such API. The window title bar is managed by the native OS. You could create an [undecorated](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UNDECORATED) stage and implement your own title bar, though that's not ideal.

Comment: You could also put all this information in a `ToolBar` placed at the top of your scene, though that will obviously cost you vertical space.

Comment: In theory, you can do this by passing [StageStyle.UNIFIED](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/StageStyle.html#UNIFIED) to `Stage.initStyle`, but I am not aware of any platform where it actually works.

Comment: I just found it, I switched up to c# uwp. Thanks everyone for your responces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which kind of customization you're trying to do, I recommend using **JNA/JNI** and **SWT** libs, you'll find guides and infos about them here:

JNA: https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

JNI: https://www.baeldung.com/jni

SWT: https://www.eclipse.org/swt

For native support of title bar customization, try switching to another language if you don't mind porting your code to c# or c++ on dotNet framework, you'll find documentations about it here:

.net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/

Title bar customization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar

Comment: I wanted a Search box and Profile Picture to show in the title bar, anyway I switched to c#